# Android Intent.ACTION_VIEW in a specific folder show others folder's files

Tags: android, android-intent

i have a little problem, I need show the images/videos form a specific folder via default gallery, but when i throw the intent, the gallery not shows only files from the folder that i pass to te data intent, the gallery shows all images to the device. The code that i use is:

```
Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/folder/");

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(selectedUri);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need show the images/videos form a specific folder via default gallery

That is not possible. There are **thousands** of device models. These ship with **hundreds** of different "default gallery" apps. None of them have to have some sort of API to allow you to request that they view some directory's worth of images.

Activities responding to `ACTION_VIEW` with a MIME type of `image/*` will expect that the `Uri` points to a single image. There is no MIME type for a directory, and there is no requirement that any gallery app honor such a MIME type even if one existed.

Comment: thanks, i have create a custom gallery activity for display and manage the images and videos in my app.